# how to add data to local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on one game application.
 Intially  I made two loaclstorage, one is userCard and another CompCard and I added 3 cricket players cards details to both the local storage.

My  2 local storage and its deatils :

```
var user_Card =  [["Nixon", "McLean", "West Indies", 
                   45, 314, 0, 1, "12.07", "37.58", 
                   46, 3, 21, 8, 
                   "img/cards/7RBKWQPJAG_NixonMcLean.jpg", 1], 
                  ["Brian", "McMillan", "South Africa", 78,  
                    841, 1, 0, "23.36", "36.98", 70, 4, 32, 43,
                    "img/cards/Y9U5UKA60O_BrianMcMillan.jpg", 2], 
                  ["Craig", "McMillan", "New Zealand", 197, 4707, 3,
                    28, "28.18", "35.04", 49, 3, 20, 44, 
                   "img/cards/WE0NUNG80C_CraigMcMillan.jpg", 3]
                 ];             

var comp_Card =  [["Geoff", "Miller", "England", 25, 136, 0, 0, 
                  "8.5", "32.52", 25, 3, 27, 4, 
                  "img/cards/7ZPIQXC19H_GeoffMiller.jpg", 4], 
                  ["Kyle", "Mills", "New Zealand", 165, 1016, 
                    0, 2, "15.87", "26.74", 235, 5, 25, 40, 
                   "img/cards/P43DTA4ZCX_KyleMills.jpg", 5], 
                  ["Minhazul", "Adedin", "Bangladesh", 27, 453, 0, 2, 
                   "18.87", "39.3", 13, 2, 39, 2, 
                    "img/cards/CC8ENY3E09_MinhazulAdedin.jpg", 6]
                  ];

userCard =JSON.parse(localStorage['user_Card']);
compCard =JSON.parse(localStorage['comp_Card']);
```

When I retrieving all cards details are coming, `usercard[0]` and `compcard [0]` is the first card, `usercard[1]` is the second card, `usercard[2]` is the third card,

My question is when I play the game, the if usercard wins, I want add the loosing compcard to usercard local storgae. And if compcard wins add the loosing usercard to compcard local storage.

Assume `userCard[0]` is the first card
           `compcard[0]` is the first card

When I playing the game,if  `userCard[0]` wins, I want to add loosing `compcard[0]` to  localstorage userCard and if  `compCard[0]` wins, I want to add loosing `usercard[0]` to  localstorage compCard

Please provide me the the solution for this.

Comment: localstorage holds strings.

Comment: yes, but i want to know how to add the cards to loacl storage when who wins

Comment: take the object, add the new card by pushing it to the end of the array and using JSON.stringify to get it back into storage...

Comment: i trid it storing, can me provide me the code please

Comment: What did you try that is not working?

Comment: userCard=JSON.stringify(compCard[0]); when usercard wins and i alerting alert(usercard); it showing only one card details

Comment: `compCard[0])` <---- You have one card referenced!

Answer (score 1):

How you can read from [Offline Technologies](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)

> Web Storage simply provides a key-value mapping, e.g.
>   localStorage["name"] = username;. Unfortunately, present
>   implementations only support string-to-string mappings, so you need to
>   serialise and de-serialise other data structures. You can do so using
>   JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse().

so you should try something like this:

```
var userCard =JSON.parse(localStorage.['user_Card']);
userCard.push(compCard[0]);

localStorage.['user_Card'] = JSON.stringify(userCard));
```